# Read XML with namespace in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4, mule-esb

I am trying to read an xml and put if else conditions on a certain tag. If data exists, I need to print true otherwise false. Below is the sample XML that I am trying to read:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<ns01:active xmlns:ns01="http://Atlas.Schemas.Policy/1.0">
  <Id>
    <groupId>66d9057f-0951-4970-86d6-4d69d3572abe</groupId>
  </Id>
</ns01:active>
```

I tried using this dataweave code but it does not work me:

```
 if(payload.active.Id.groupId != null) "true" else "False"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is unrelated to the usage of a namespace. Note that there is no way to represent `null` in plain XML.

If you want to return true if the element exists (ie there is a key with that name) independent of its value (ie the content inside the element) then you can use the [key-present selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors) (ie add a `?` question mark after the key name).

If instead you want to see if the value of the element is empty you could use the function [isEmpty()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-isempty). You can negate its return value using the not operator (`!`).

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    keyPresentSelector: payload.active.Id.groupId?,
    hasValue: !isEmpty(payload.active.Id.groupId)
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "keyPresentSelector": true,
  "hasValue": true
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks @aled. I have another question about reading an XML. I'll post a new question for that and hopefully find an answer for it. Thanks again!